# Different relationship between 2 entities

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema, entity-relationship, erd

In my project I have a part where says -

> An **airline** has many **flights**
>   and each flight has one **source (airport)** and one or more **destinations (airports)**. For each source destination pairs, you have to record the ***distance***.

According to this statement I have done an erd like this -

```
                   _________
                  | Airline |
                   ---------
                       |
                      has
                   ____|____ 
                  | Flights |
                   ---------
               /               \
            s.has             d.has
      _______/______       ______\_______
     |source_airport|     | dest_airport |
      --------------       --------------
```

- Now I am having problem with the last attribute ***distance***. How should I place it with the above erd?
- Alternately I am thinking the **Airport** will be a single entity where **Flights** & **Airport** will have a relationship between them. But if this happens how to distinguish the ***source*** and ***destination*** part between them as well as solve the problem with ***distance*** attribute?

Comment: One option would be to store latitude/longitude pairs for each departure/arrival point.  Then use something like the Haversine formula to compute the distance.  Many databases support geospatial functions which could help here.

Comment: Will the source and destination airports for flights change over time or is it static?@sinDbad

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So if I use latitude/longitude, should I go with the above erd with 2 airport entities for **source** & **destination** or is there any alternate?

Comment: @PrasathRajasekaran Well this detail is not given in the document, but let's assume the source & destination airports will change over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment.  You may represent a given flight using two tables, one for locations, and the other a junction table relating one location to another.

```
CREATE TABLE locations (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    latitude DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    longitude DOUBLE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE flights (
    source_id INT NOT NULL,
    dest_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (source_id, dest_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (source_id) REFERENCES locations(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (dest_id) REFERENCES locations(id)
);
```

So, now a flight is simply an entry in the `flights` junction table.  The metadata for each airport sits in the `locations` table.

Comment: Thank you for the brief code explanation, but I only wanted the erd presentation of this. According to the code given by you can you tell me how the erd will look like?

Comment: Both the source and destination airports would "have" a longitude and latitude, though I might even draw both locations as one box, to emphasize that this information is coming from the same single table.

Comment: sorry for late comment. As I am a slow learner and also new to sql, finally I understand everything now. I will just name the `locations` table to `airport` and everything will work as fine, thanks for the help.